# Django admin - set a field when another one is entered

Tags: python, django, django-admin

And sorry if my question was already asked on SO but I could not find the answer I'm looking for.

I created a `Model` with an `ImageField` and a `DateField`. In my django automatic admin (django 1.4), I have the corresponding `ModelAdmin`: I'd like to set the date from the image when the `ImageField` is populated by the user. To sum it up, I'd like to get the hand when the `ImageField` was chosen, for instance by overriding a kind of post-choice method.

How can I do that ? I could read in django doc that a `clean` method exists but the way/time it's called is unclear to me.

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override model's `save()` method or better use `pre_save` [signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/signals/). Inside you can check if the object has an image but doesn't have a date, and set the date to `datetime.datetime.now()`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'd like more to be called when the `ImageField` was entered, so much before save, is there a signal or so that could be used ?

Comment: You mean - before uploading it to server? You can fill a hidden field with current timestamp using JS then.

Comment: I became aware of the fact that my request is silly (or at least complicated, as indeed the image was not uploaded yet). So I took the decision to override the `save` method.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Image model from django-filer:
https://github.com/stefanfoulis/django-filer/blob/develop/filer/models/imagemodels.py

You could do something similar in the save method.

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.date_taken is None:
        try:
            exif_date = self.exif.get('DateTimeOriginal', None)
            if exif_date is not None:
                d, t = str.split(exif_date.values)
                year, month, day = d.split(':')
                hour, minute, second = t.split(':')
                self.date_taken = datetime(
                                   int(year), int(month), int(day),
                                   int(hour), int(minute), int(second))
        except:
            pass
    if self.date_taken is None:
        self.date_taken = datetime.now()
    self.has_all_mandatory_data = self._check_validity()
    try:
        # do this more efficient somehow?
        self.file.seek(0)
        self._width, self._height = PILImage.open(self.file).size
    except Exception:
        # probably the image is missing. nevermind.
        pass
    super(Image, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, as explained above after ilvar's answer, I'd like more to be called when the `ImageField` was entered.